# SAS using encrypted (PWENCODE) in EMAILPW= option

Tags: email, encryption, passwords, sas

My code works fine using plain text code, but fails when I use an encrypted password

filename File email emailsys = VIM  emailid= "&pa_usr"  emailpw= "{sasenc}39AAD23E148A9555508AC84447181DFF" ;

Anyone know what I should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer back from SAS:

> Sorry to say that this is a Defect.
>
> The support for encoded/encrypted email passwords will be available in SAS 9.2 TS2M3.
>
> Please do let me know if you have any further questions."